# Firestore doc delete expected to delete 1 person, but deletes all similar documents as well

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a Firestore database to store information about users connected to a session in my app. To leave, users press a leave button which then is supposed to delete their own data from the database. Here's my code for deleting a client:

```
  _deleteAClientFromDB() async {
    //get specific user in users
    var userLobby = await users
        .where('lobbyCode', isEqualTo: _lobbyCode)
        .where('userRole', isEqualTo: 2)
        .where('userID', isEqualTo: _userID)
        .get();
    userLobby.docs.forEach((document) {
      document.reference.delete();
    });
  }
```

this code is very similar to my function to delete all users from the database with the added "where" of the user ID. The `userID` is a string field that is unique per user. However, I'm pretty sure what's happening is that when I try to run this function on a device, it somehow runs the function on all devices? That's the only reason I can think of since if `userID` is not the same as the one in firestore it wouldn't be retrieved. I initialize with this function to extract my `SharedPreferences`:

```
  Future<String> _getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(
      () {
        _lobbyCode = (prefs.getString('lobbyCode'));
        _userID = (prefs.getString('userID'));
        _isHost = prefs.getBool('isHost') ?? false;
      },
    );
```

I'm not sure why the function is deleting all documents with the `userRole` of 2 while not only deleting the document with the `userID` of `_userID`(locally stored data). Does anyone understand what it is that I'm doing wrong?

```
E/flutter ( 8795): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s)
E/flutter ( 8795): #0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:267:57)
E/flutter ( 8795): #1      _LobbyWidgetState._deleteAClientFromDB (package:percepto/lobby.dart:350:46)
E/flutter ( 8795): #2      _LobbyWidgetState._showClientConfirmDialog.<anonymous closure> (package:percepto/lobby.dart:488:9)
```

It seems like there really is something wrong with `_userID`, I tried to do a log of `log("This is what userID is:" + _userID);` and was met with these errors. I'm not sure why it could be an invalid argument because it was initialized as an empty string and set from the device's local storage.

Comment: have you checked the value `_userID` by logging it?

Comment: Please refer the realtime example of CRUD from the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960948/14950155

Comment: My guess would be that the value of `_userID` is not what you are expecting it to be, and this is causing this behaviour, as mentioned by @MuthuThavamani. Try logging it and share it's current value and if it is the expected.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to print it out with `print()` before but log seemed to have shown me an error. I updated the question to show it.

Comment: So the problem is your shared preferences, is it populating the other variables? Are you able to log the values of `prefs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for recommending me to check _userID, after I saw the log error I double checked where I set the `shared_preferences` and apparently I named `userID` `id`. So I was trying to extract data from a prefs that didn't exist.