# Deleting docs in cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to code a todo App linked with cloud firestore. I want that when i tap on my tile which is a Gesture Detector, the task is deleted on firestore but it won't work.
Here's my code for my Function i use and all things that are necessary.

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

///

```
void deleteTask(){
_firestore.collection("todos").doc().delete();

}
```

///

```
child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: (){
          deleteTask();
        },
        child: Container(
```

Comment: you are not passing the document ID in `doc()`. Without valid document reference you cannot perform delete.

Comment: Well I don't have the reference cause its automatically generated for each new task in firebase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting Firestore Data in Flutter List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959381/deleting-firestore-data-in-flutter-list-view)

Comment: @elios_cama Save your Todo objects with doc ID when you set the data to Firestore. If user deletes it, so you can access to it.

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş I can't figure out how to save it

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting new doc Firebase probably this kind of code you use:

```
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  DocumentReference ref = db.collection('tasks').doc();
  ref.set(
    {'field': data},
  );
  // save your ref.id here in order to let user remove the task eventually
```

This piece of code you wrote just puts a new document on a field. Now when you create or populate your Task class, you need to obtain document ID in order to delete it.

```
removeTask(String documentID) async {
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  DocumentReference ref = db.collection('tasks').doc(documentID);
  ref.delete();
}

// ref.id gives you the doc ID. Put it in your Task class when fetching docs 
// so if user wants to delete any document, he/she can delete it.
```