# Flutter and Firebase: Update collection documents on retrieve data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple **flutter** and **firebase** application where users can store customers with their loans and payments.

I want to display the customer's list with their balance amount ie `totalLoanAmount - totalPaymentsAmount`

customer document has only three properties which are name, address, and phone. **My goal is to retrieve the customer's documents and for each document add the amount property which is a balance of the remaining loan (debts).**

Here are the screenshots of the database structure in the firebase console
[image: Customers Collection]

[image: Subcollections - debts(loans)]

And below is the code I try but nothing was done.

```
class CustomerService {


 final FirebaseFirestore _instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getCustomer() {
    CollectionReference customers = _instance.collection('customers');

customers.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  // Here I try to loop through all customer documents to get access to its values
  snapshot.docs.map((element) {
    customers.doc(element.id).collection('debts').get().then((value) {
      // Here I try to get subcollections which is '/debts' and try to calculate total amount of all debts
      double amount;
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        amount += element.data()['amount'];
      });
      // I dont know how can I attach this amount to customer document to get the following result
      /*
        {
          name: "Somename",
          address: "Someaddress",
          phone: "09645778",
          amount: 1000
        }
      */
    });
  });
});

return customers.snapshots();
 }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please refer the real time example https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960948/14950155

Comment: Are you still facing this issue, or was the comment above helpful for you?