# I want to delete a document from collection in Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a document from a collection in Firebase Firestore. I wrote a method, but it's not working and does not delete anything. I need help, and this is my method:

```
final couponsReference =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Coupons");

  Future<void> Deletecoupon() async {
// displayToastMassage('try1', context);


String s=couponsReference.doc().id;
couponsReference.doc(s).delete().catchError((s){
  print(s);
});
displayToastMassage('Coupn Code has been deleted sucsseflly', context);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960948/14950155 --> Refer this to get more details about delete, add from fires tore

Comment: I suggest you have look at this post on [deleting documents in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180076/how-to-delete-document-from-firestore-using-where-clause/47180442#47180442)

Answer (score 0):

To delete a document you need the documentId of that specific document. In your deletecoupon method you should pass in the documentId and could then use the await keyword to => await couponsReference.doc(documentId).delete();

Answer (score 0):

To delete a particular document from a collection is very easy you just need one thing that documents documents I'd which you want to delete :

```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection("blogs").doc(widget.postid).delete();
```