# i can't update data, re-add products every time, i want to update

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
class DetailedCountingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final String countDate;
final String standName;
const DetailedCountingScreen(
  {required this.countDate, required this.standName});

@override
_DetailedCountingScreenState createState() => _DetailedCountingScreenState();
}

class _DetailedCountingScreenState extends State<DetailedCountingScreen> {
  final firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  List<String> productNames = [];
  List<int> soldPieces = [];
  List<int> countedPieces = [];
  List<double> productPrices = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
     firebaseRef
    .child('Sayımlar')
    .child(widget.standName)
    .child('${widget.countDate}')
    .onValue
    .listen((event) {
  final snapshot = event.snapshot.value ?? {};
  final countedProductsMap = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot);
  countedProductsMap.forEach((key, value) {
    setState(() {

      productNames.add(value['ürünİsmi']);
      soldPieces.add(value['satılanMiktar']);
      countedPieces.add(value['sayılanMiktar']);
      productPrices.add(value['ürünFiyatı']);

    });
  });
});
super.initState();
}

     Widget countsCard(
     {required int soldPiece,
     required double productPrice,
    required int countedPiece,
    required String productName,
  required int thePieceBeforeCount,
  required double totalPrice}) {
   return Card(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: ListTile(
    isThreeLine: true,
    title: Text(
      productName.toUpperCase(),
      style: kBlackTS.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    subtitle: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text('Sayılan Adet: $countedPiece', style: kBlackTS),
            emptySpaceWidth(context, 0.04),
            Text('Satılan Adet: $soldPiece', style: kBlackTS),
            emptySpaceWidth(context, 0.04),
            Text('Sayım Öncesi Adet: $thePieceBeforeCount',
                style: kBlackTS),
          ],
        ),
        emptySpaceHeight(context, 0.015),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text('Satış Fiyatı: ${productPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)} ₺',
                style: kBlackTS),
            emptySpaceWidth(context, 0.04),
            Text('Toplam Tutar: ${totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)} ₺',
                style: kBlackTS),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
     ),
    );
  }

   FloatingActionButton get _invoiceFAB {
  return FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade700,
    child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.fileInvoice, color: Colors.white),
    onPressed: () {});
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   CustomAppBar customAppBar = CustomAppBar(
    context: context,
    colour: Colors.blue.shade700,
    title: '${widget.countDate} Tarihli Sayımlar');
   return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
    appBar: customAppBar.customAppBar,
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: productNames != [] ? productNames.length : 0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              double total = soldPieces[index] * productPrices[index];
              int thePieceBeforeCount =
                  soldPieces[index] + countedPieces[index];
              return countsCard(
                  soldPiece: soldPieces[index],
                  productPrice: productPrices[index],
                  countedPiece: countedPieces[index],
                  productName: productNames[index],
                  thePieceBeforeCount: thePieceBeforeCount,
                  totalPrice: total);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
       floatingActionButton: _invoiceFAB,
      ),
   );
```

I don't want to update the data, instead it re-adds it, can you help me how to fix it? what should i change, how should the code be? I want to update the products I added, it is necessary for my homework and I don't know what to do. I need help on what code to write for the update thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid retrieving firebase data inside initState method
- Use SteamBuilder or FutureBuilder based on your requirement
- I prefer SteamBuilder for your case
- Refer the doc for more reference https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html
- Refer the example to fetch from firebase and maintain https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960948/14950155